# ZFS - Solaris 10 doesn't see disks after reboot on HP Pro DL380 G7

Tags: solaris, hp-proliant, zfs, hp-smart-array

The current box has 2 logical drives, shown in P410i Array Controller (F8 during POST) as:

- Logical Drive 1 - 2 SAS 72GB HD Raid10  <----root pool disk
- Logical Drive 2 - 4 SAS 146GB HD Raid 5 <----data disk

And this is what it shows in the OS :

```
bash-3.2# echo | format
Searching for disks...done

AVAILABLE DISK SELECTIONS:
       0. c0t0d0 <HP     -LOGICAL VOLUME -5.06 cyl 17841 alt 2 hd 255 sec 63>
          /pci@0,0/pci8086,3408@1/pci103c,3245@0/sd@0,0
       1. c0t1d0 <HP-LOGICAL VOLUME-5.70-410.10GB>
          /pci@0,0/pci8086,3408@1/pci103c,3245@0/sd@1,0

bash-3.2# zpool status
  pool: rpool
 state: ONLINE
 scan: none requested
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        rpool       ONLINE       0     0     0
          c0t0d0s0  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors

  pool: rpool-app
 state: ONLINE
 scan: none requested
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        rpool-app   ONLINE       0     0     0
          c0t1d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
```

The size of current rpool (c0t0d0) is too small which is 72GB. I want to increase the rpool by putting in new hard disks (2 SAS 146GB). After I create the new logical drive for these 2 drives, it appears in the Controller as Logical Volume 3 and in the OS as c0t2d0. 
In the OS, i format c0t2d0, attach it to the rpool to have it mirrored then i detach the c0t0d0. I make sure the new disk is bootable by setting

> eeprom bootpath= new device

When i reboot the server and access the controller (F8), i also go to Select Boot Volume and select Logical Volume 3 as the new current boot lun. The server is able to boot up and picking up the new boot device correctly. However, I don't see 2 previous disks there anymore (c0t0d0 and c0t1d0).

```
bash-3.2# echo | format
Searching for disks...done


AVAILABLE DISK SELECTIONS:
       0. c0t2d0 <HP     -LOGICAL VOLUME -5.06 cyl 17841 alt 2 hd 255 sec 63>
          /pci@0,0/pci8086,3408@1/pci103c,3245@0/sd@2,0
```

I tried everything, devfsadm or cfgadm and reboot many times to check the status of those Logical Drives in the Controller, they are still there with OK status. But i don't know why i no longer see them in the OS. c0t0d0 is the old boot disk that i don't need anymore, but c0t1d0 is the data disk and i need it to show up here.  Do you have any clues?

Comment: Do you have `HPQacucli` available?

Comment: Do you need to do a reconfiguration boot (boot -r) off the new disk. It's been a while since I had to deal with Solaris at that level.

Comment: Yup I did reboot -- -r but it didnt worke either.

Comment: no i dont have HPQacucli installed on the server. Do you think it can help figure out the problem? I tried to remove 2 drives that made up Logical Drive 1, reboot the server and access the Controller and i still see Logical Drive 1 there.  Is there anyway to reset the number of actual configured logical drives in the Controller?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation to you would have been to replace the 72GB disks with 146GB drives, one-by-one, allowing each to rebuild. That would then allow you to expand the logical drive from 72GB to 146GB. This would require the use of an offline utility or the `hpacucli` or `hpssacli` tool to perform the expansion.

Within ZFS, the new LUN size could probably be accessed after a `zpool online -e` to expand to the full 146GB.

The approach of copying the root pool the way you did may be fraught, but it *seems* like you've taken the right steps. But short of a reinstall, I don't know how you can make the new pair of disks bootable.

---

Edit: Your issue seems to be the logical drives.

I don't know if the new drive changes the enumeration of the old drives. But if the block devices are present in the controller configuration, they should be available in the OS.

Comment: I make the new pair of disks bootable by going to the Array Controller, ie F8 when reboot. There I see option Select boot volume. I select Logical Drive 3 as a new boot volume and save the config.

I just installed HPQacucli and run it on the server. Still see all logical drives and physical drives there with OK status, but the OS still doesn't see Logical Drive 1 and Logical Drive 2.